# Trigger event or message from webchat window to bot(MS bot framework)

Tags: javascript, botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

### Using the below code to generate an event to the bot thru directline.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="bot" />
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
        <script>
            var user = {
                id: 'user-id',
                name: 'user name'
            };
            var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
                token: 'MYTOKENHERE',
                user: user
            });
            BotChat.App({
                user: user,
                botConnection: botConnection,
                bot: { id: 'bot-id', name: 'bot name' },
                resize: 'detect'
            }, document.getElementById("bot"));
            botConnection
                .postActivity({
                    from: user,
                    name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
                    type: 'event',
                    value: ''
                })
                .subscribe(function (id) {
                    console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I have code to handle any event/message which reach from the bot. When I type hi or any messages it will work. But not automatically while I load the chatbot as a conversationupdate activity as promised by MS bot framework documentation.
Can any one please help.

Comment: Marking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it looks like you are using Web Chat v3, which is depreciated and no longer supported. I would recommend switching to Web Chat v4, especially if you are just getting started. Note, Web Chat v4 does work with v3 Bots. Take a look at the [Web Chat Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples) to get started with v4.

Also, I'm assuming you're talking about the Welcome Message not being sent properly in Web Chat. If that's the case, take a look at this [GitHub answer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2120#issuecomment-516056614). It discusses how to properly send a Welcome Message in Web Chat. Some of the principles discussed in the answer still apply to Web Chat v3 if you don't intend to switch to v4.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the request on your bot code. Check for the "requestWelcomeDialog" like so. This should be in your MainDialog.

```
   protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "requestWelcomeDialog")
            {
                //send activity here
            }
        }
```